# What is the best/right way to vertical centralize this with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to vertical centralize the "red" square with text. I have some inner `<a>` inside the div, doens't know if this affect something... The css below works, but seems to have too much `vertical-align: middle;` in every single tag. Someone know how to make this more simple with the same html tree? Thanks!

**Html:**

```
<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<span>Testing...</span>
```

**Css:**

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a{
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

span{
    font-size: 26px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sGgZb/6/

Comment: Sorry for the completely off-topic comment, but nice rep-score :)

Comment: hahahahaha. so please don't vote up

Comment: There's a pretty good article on this here: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: The taller elements are the only ones that need their vertical-alignment adjusted.  If your elements are of unknown sizes, then all of them need it.  Also, vertical-align only works on inline or table-cell elements.

Answer (score 3):

Only the span needs the vertical-align rule.

```
span{
    font-size: 26px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sGgZb/11/)**

Comment: Well in your new case then the div needs it too.

Comment: If double vertical align is some kind of monkeypatch because it should work with only on the first or the last. +-

Answer (score 0):

Use pseudo-elements since this is a purely stylistic enhancement. No additional markup is required, and your CSS is cleaner.

**HTML:**

```
<span>Testing...</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span {
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
span::before {
    content: " ";
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f00;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sGgZb/18/)

Comment: This is good for cleaner code, but is less natural (margin-top: -2.5px) then delegating the browser to calculate the vertical align to it =)

Comment: Edited to use inline-block, rather than absolute positioning. :)

Comment: Could add a negative top-margin. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to accomplish is to not use as many vertical aligns, then I accomplished the same effect without the container div and putting `inline-block` on the a itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/sGgZb/19/